# Android NULL Pointer Exception and Fragment data transmission

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, fragment, runtimeexception

I am a beginner at android studio, I have a mission to redesign the app. I use the Fragment. But when I run my app, it has stopped and there is no error in my Gradle. I looked for many website to solve my question, but still have no idea.

I have some questions below.

1. How can I fix the java.lang.RuntimeException (NULL Pointer Exception) ?

```
09-30 02:59:56.574 17706-17706/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
09-30 02:59:56.574 17706-17706/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
09-30 02:59:56.996 17722-17722/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
09-30 02:59:56.996 17722-17722/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
09-30 02:59:57.090 17734-17734/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                   Process: tw.com.flag.parking22, PID: 17734
                                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{tw.com.flag.parking22/tw.com.flag.parking22.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
                                                    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
                                                       at tw.com.flag.parking22.MainActivity.init(MainActivity.java:102)
                                                       at tw.com.flag.parking22.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:71)
                                                       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
09-30 02:59:57.211 1160-1160/? E/EGL_emulation: tid 1160: eglCreateSyncKHR(1865): error 0x3004 (EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE)
09-30 03:02:15.409 2159-19872/com.google.android.gms E/Herrevad: [350] RemoteReportsRefreshChimeraService.a: want to send authenticated request, but no Google account on device
09-30 03:02:15.445 1998-2721/com.google.android.gms.persistent E/SQLiteLog: (2067) abort at 31 in [INSERT INTO pending_ops(source,tag,requires_charging,target_package,source_version,required_network_type,flex_time,target_class,runtime,retry_strategy,last_runtime,period,task_type,job_id,user_
09-30 03:02:15.445 1998-2721/com.google.android.gms.persistent E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting source=4 tag=NetworkReportService requires_charging=0 target_package=com.google.android.gms source_version=11509000 required_network_type=2 flex_time=3600000 target_class=com.google.android.gms.common.stats.net.NetworkReportService runtime=1506742923454 retry_strategy={"maximum_backoff_seconds":{"3600":0},"initial_backoff_seconds":{"30":0},"retry_policy":{"0":0}} last_runtime=0 period=7200000 task_type=1 job_id=-1 user_id=0
                                                                                 android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: pending_ops.tag, pending_ops.target_class, pending_ops.target_package, pending_ops.user_id (code 2067)
                                                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForLastInsertedRowId(Native Method)
                                                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteConnection.java:782)
                                                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteSession.java:788)
                                                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:86)
                                                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1471)
                                                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1341)
                                                                                     at swi.a(:com.google.android.gms@11509280:208)
                                                                                     at sxo.a(:com.google.android.gms@11509280:64)
                                                                                     at sxp.handleMessage(:com.google.android.gms@11509280:29)
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                                     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
09-30 03:02:15.446 1998-2721/com.google.android.gms.persistent E/NetworkScheduler: Error persisting task: com.google.android.gms/.common.stats.net.NetworkReportService{u=0 tag="NetworkReportService" trigger=window{period=7200s,flex=3600s,earliest=5988s,latest=9588s} requirements=[NET_ANY] attributes=[PERSISTED,RECURRING] scheduled=2388s last_run=N/A jid=N/A status=PENDING retries=0}
09-30 03:02:15.474 1170-1578/? E/Drm: Failed to find drm plugin
09-30 03:02:15.563 2159-2680/com.google.android.gms E/Volley: [129] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 307 for https://android.googleapis.com/nova/herrevad/network_quality_info
09-30 03:02:15.888 1998-2721/com.google.android.gms.persistent E/SQLiteLog: (2067) abort at 31 in [INSERT INTO pending_ops(source,tag,requires_charging,target_package,source_version,required_network_type,flex_time,target_class,runtime,retry_strategy,last_runtime,period,task_type,job_id,user_
09-30 03:02:15.888 1998-2721/com.google.android.gms.persistent E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting source=4 tag=AggregationTaskTag requires_charging=0 target_package=com.google.android.gms source_version=11509000 required_network_type=2 flex_time=600000 target_class=com.google.android.gms.checkin.EventLogService runtime=1506741123628 retry_strategy={"maximum_backoff_seconds":{"3600":0},"initial_backoff_seconds":{"30":0},"retry_policy":{"0":0}} last_runtime=0 period=1800000 task_type=1 job_id=-1 user_id=0
                                                                                 android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: pending_ops.tag, pending_ops.target_class, pending_ops.target_package, pending_ops.user_id (code 2067)
                                                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForLastInsertedRowId(Native Method)
                                                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteConnection.java:782)
                                                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteSession.java:788)
                                                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:86)
                                                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1471)
                                                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1341)
                                                                                     at swi.a(:com.google.android.gms@11509280:208)
                                                                                     at sxo.a(:com.google.android.gms@11509280:64)
                                                                                     at sxp.handleMessage(:com.google.android.gms@11509280:29)
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                                     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
09-30 03:02:15.888 1998-2721/com.google.android.gms.persistent E/NetworkScheduler: Error persisting task: com.google.android.gms/.checkin.EventLogService{u=0 tag="AggregationTaskTag" trigger=window{period=1800s,flex=600s,earliest=1787s,latest=2387s} requirements=[NET_ANY] attributes=[PERSISTED,RECURRING] scheduled=587s last_run=N/A jid=N/A status=PENDING retries=0}
09-30 03:03:37.417 1170-1578/? E/audio_hw_generic: Error opening input stream format 1, channel_mask 0010, sample_rate 16000
09-30 03:30:15.406 2159-21157/com.google.android.gms E/Herrevad: [355] RemoteReportsRefreshChimeraService.a: want to send authenticated request, but no Google account on device
09-30 03:30:15.511 2159-21162/com.google.android.gms E/ZappConnFactory: Unable to bind to PlayStore
09-30 03:30:15.518 2159-21168/com.google.android.gms E/ZappLogOperation: Unable to bind to Phonesky
09-30 03:30:15.526 2159-21162/com.google.android.gms E/ZappConnFactory: Unable to bind to PlayStore
09-30 03:30:15.526 2159-21162/com.google.android.gms E/ZappConnFactory: Unable to bind to PlayStore
09-30 03:30:15.551 2159-2678/com.google.android.gms E/Volley: [127] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 307 for https://android.googleapis.com/nova/herrevad/network_quality_info
09-30 03:30:15.572 1170-1578/? E/Drm: Failed to find drm plugin
09-30 03:30:22.524 2159-2159/com.google.android.gms E/ActivityThread: Service com.google.android.gms.chimera.GmsIntentOperationService has leaked ServiceConnection ctn@2f714ea6 that was originally bound here
                                                                      android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.google.android.gms.chimera.GmsIntentOperationService has leaked ServiceConnection ctn@2f714ea6 that was originally bound here
                                                                          at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:1077)
                                                                          at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:971)
                                                                          at android.app.ContextImpl.bindServiceCommon(ContextImpl.java:1774)
                                                                          at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1757)
                                                                          at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:539)
                                                                          at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:539)
                                                                          at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:539)
                                                                          at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:539)
                                                                          at com.google.android.gms.chimera.container.zapp.ZappLogOperation.onHandleIntent(:com.google.android.gms@11509280:1)
                                                                          at com.google.android.chimera.IntentOperation.onHandleIntent(:com.google.android.gms@11509280:2)
                                                                          at bwy.run(:com.google.android.gms@11509280:10)
                                                                          at bwv.run(:com.google.android.gms@11509280:14)
                                                                          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
                                                                          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
                                                                          at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
09-30 03:44:15.607 1998-2721/com.google.android.gms.persistent E/SQLiteLog: (2067) abort at 31 in [INSERT INTO pending_ops(source,tag,requires_charging,target_package,source_version,required_network_type,flex_time,target_class,runtime,retry_strategy,last_runtime,period,task_type,job_id,user_
09-30 03:44:15.607 1998-2721/com.google.android.gms.persistent E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting source=4 tag=AggregationTaskTag requires_charging=0 target_package=com.google.android.gms source_version=11509000 required_network_type=2 flex_time=600000 target_class=com.google.android.gms.checkin.EventLogService runtime=1506743055606 retry_strategy={"maximum_backoff_seconds":{"3600":0},"initial_backoff_seconds":{"30":0},"retry_policy":{"0":0}} last_runtime=0 period=1800000 task_type=1 job_id=-1 user_id=0
                                                                                 android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: pending_ops.tag, pending_ops.target_class, pending_ops.target_package, pending_ops.user_id (code 2067)
                                                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForLastInsertedRowId(Native Method)
                                                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteConnection.java:782)
                                                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteSession.java:788)
                                                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:86)
                                                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1471)
                                                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1341)
                                                                                     at swi.a(:com.google.android.gms@11509280:208)
                                                                                     at sxo.a(:com.google.android.gms@11509280:64)
                                                                                     at sxp.handleMessage(:com.google.android.gms@11509280:29)
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                                     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
09-30 03:44:15.607 1998-2721/com.google.android.gms.persistent E/NetworkScheduler: Error persisting task: com.google.android.gms/.checkin.EventLogService{u=0 tag="AggregationTaskTag" trigger=window{period=1800s,flex=600s,earliest=1199s,latest=1799s} requirements=[NET_ANY] attributes=[PERSISTED,RECURRING] scheduled=0s last_run=N/A jid=N/A status=PENDING retries=0}
09-30 03:44:15.637 2159-21184/com.google.android.gms E/Herrevad: [371] RemoteReportsRefreshChimeraService.a: want to send authenticated request, but no Google account on device
09-30 03:44:15.755 2159-2676/com.google.android.gms E/Volley: [126] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 307 for https://android.googleapis.com/nova/herrevad/network_quality_info
09-30 03:46:13.425 1171-1171/? E/installd: eof
09-30 03:46:13.425 1171-1171/? E/installd: failed to read size
```

Here is the main activity code

```java
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        viewPager =(ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        PagerAdapter padapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewPager.setAdapter(padapter);
        //--------------------------------------------------------------------
        init();
        Action();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        if(newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {

        }
        else {

        }
    }

    private void init(){
        System.out.println("start---------------------");
        textView_userIDVal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_userIDVal);
        textView_parkingNoVal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_parkingNoVal);
        textView_pillarNoVal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_pillarNoVal);
        textView_colorVal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_colorVal);
        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        button_space = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_space);
        button_scan = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_scan);
        button_find = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_find);
        simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd 'at' HH");


        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD) {
            userID = Build.SERIAL;
            //-------------error start  next----------------
            textView_userIDVal.setText("User ID : " + userID);
        }

        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, 200);
        }

        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("Data", 0);
        if(sharedPreferences.contains("parkingNum") && sharedPreferences.contains("time")) {
            parkingNumtmp = sharedPreferences.getString("parkingNum", "");
            textView_parkingNoVal.setText("Parking No. : " + parkingNumtmp + "\t(" + sharedPreferences.getString("time", "") + ")");
        }

        builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setCancelable(false);
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            }
        });

        builder_timeout = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder_timeout.setTitle("REMIND");
        builder_timeout.setMessage("Do you find your car ?");
        builder_timeout.setCancelable(false);
        builder_timeout.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                try {
                    json_data = new JSONObject();
                    json_data.put("MT", "timeout");
                    json_data.put("PlaceMac", parkingNumtmp);
                    json_data.put("UserMac", userID);
                    json_write = new JSONObject();
                    json_write.put("Data", json_data);
                    json_write.put("Read", false);
                    isCloseScreen = false;
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                thread = new Thread(TCP);
                thread.start();
                timer_count = 0;
                startFlag = false;
            }
        });
        builder_timeout.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                maxTime = 10;
                maxTime = maxTime / 2;
                timer_count = 0;
                startFlag = true;
            }
        });
    }

    private void Action(){
        button_space.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    json_data = new JSONObject();
                    json_data.put("MT", "count");

                    json_write = new JSONObject();
                    json_write.put("Data", json_data);
                    json_write.put("Read", true);
                    //System.out.println(json_write + "\n");
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                thread = new Thread(TCP);
                thread.start();
                /*builder.setTitle("INFORMATION");
                builder.setMessage("All : " + "\nNow : " );
                AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
                alertDialog.show();*/
            }
        });
        button_scan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ScanActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
            }
        });

        button_find.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(parkingNumtmp != null) {
                    try {
                        maxTime = 10;
                        json_data = new JSONObject();
                        json_data.put("MT", "search");
                        json_data.put("PlaceMac", parkingNumtmp);
                        json_data.put("UserMac", userID);

                        json_write = new JSONObject();
                        json_write.put("Data", json_data);
                        json_write.put("Read", true);
                        //System.out.println(json_write + "\n");
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Don't close the screen before you find your car ! ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    thread = new Thread(TCP);
                    thread.start();
                }
                else {
                    builder.setTitle("WARNING");
                    builder.setMessage("Please scan QRcode first!");
                    AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
                    alertDialog.show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if(requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if(data != null) {
                final Barcode barcode = data.getParcelableExtra("barcode");
                parkingNumtmp = barcode.displayValue;
                Date date = new Date();
                final String time = simpleDateFormat.format(date);
                sharedPreferences.edit().putString("parkingNum", parkingNumtmp).putString("time", time).commit();
                textView_parkingNoVal.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        textView_parkingNoVal.setText("Parking No. : " + parkingNumtmp + "\t(" + time +")");
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

2. About Fragment. Is there any setting I have to do when I receive data form sever?

I want to put the received data to TextView in the another view .

Comment: which line is line number 120 in main activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `init()` function is probably try to find views inside fragments in view pager. However, at that moment, the fragments are not inflated yet, so your views in the activity are null and trying to do  operation on them gives NPE. You should use `onCreateView()` of Fragment classes to find those views. Then you may notify main activity via callback mechanism.

For example, create `FirstFragment` as follows:

```
public class FirstFragment extends Fragment {

    private OnFirstFragmentReadyListener callback;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);

        // This makes sure that the container activity has implemented the callback.
        try {
            callback = (OnFirstFragmentReadyListener) context;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFirstFragmentReadyListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        // Notify the parent activity that the fragment is inflated.
        callback.onFirstFragmentReady();
    }

    public interface OnFirstFragmentReadyListener {
        void onFirstFragmentReady();
    }
}
```

Let the layout of `FirstFragment` as follows (referenced above as `fragment_first`):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/first_label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Assume we created two more similar fragment classes named as `SecondFragment` and `ThirdFragment`. Then the activity should be like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements FirstFragment.OnFirstFragmentReadyListener,
        SecondFragment.OnSecondFragmentReadyListener, ThirdFragment.OnThirdFragmentReadyListener {

    ...

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        viewPager =(ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        PagerAdapter pagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);

        // Don't call these functions here, spread them into callbacks.
        // init();
        // Action();
    }

    @Override
    public void onFirstFragmentReady() {
        TextView firstTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.first_label);
        ...
        // Now you have the views from FirstFragment instance.
        // You can now call setText() or setOnClickListener() here.
    }

    @Override
    public void onSecondFragmentReady() {
        TextView secondTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.second_label);
        ...
        // Now you have the views from SecondFragment instance.
        // You can now call setText() or setOnClickListener() here.
    }

    @Override
    public void onThirdFragmentReady() {
        TextView thirdTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.third_label);
        ...
        // Now you have the views from ThirdFragment instance.
        // You can now call setText() or setOnClickListener() here.
    }
}
```

Although this code works, this may not be the best way. I think it is better to do operations on views like setting texts or assigning OnClickListeners in fragments itself. If you need to notify a fragment after an action happened in the parent activity, you can implement public methods inside fragments and you can call them from the parent activity when needed.

Comment: At first thank for your answer! Do you mean that I have to find out the object ID in the fragment class with findViewById function and If I want to change the content of TextView I have to use callback mechanism in MainActivity?

Comment: Yes, I will provide some code later today.

Comment: Thanks for  help!!!!

Comment: This  information is very helpful to me!!  I will keep trying . 

And thank you "Very" much to solve my confusion.

Answer (score 0):

In fragment you should call the function in `onCreateView` function(reason as mention by @Mehmed) which is something like below:

```
 @Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

   // Inflate the layout for this fragment
   View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_fragment, container, false);
   //all findViewById;
   TextView yourTextView = (Text)view.findViewById(R.id.yourTextView);


   //here call for your function 
    init();
   // any other function goes here


  return view;
  }
```

Comment: that is another question..do my answer help u for this question's problem??

Comment: Thanks for your answer !  I want to create 3 pages (fragment one,two,three respectively). 

My project contains:
MainActivity.java>that extends FragmentActivity  ,<FragmantOne.java>  <FragmantTwo.java>, <FragmantThree.java>, <pagerAdapter.java> 

There are some buttons and textViews into them. My question is , If I want to change the content of TextView when I receive the data from Server, what should  I do in my program? 

To use setText method  in my " fragment one .java"  ? Or
 in the MainActivity ?

Thanks!!

Comment: oh,Sorry ...I am on the class... So I will try it as soon as go home 